# c# , date time conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to change the variable declared in long to `DateTime` but how can I?

I used the date time conversion like this but it throws an exception:

> "Invalid cast from 'Int64' to 'DateTime'."...

The code is here ..

```
private long TotalDuration;
TotalDuration += pa.CalcDurationForStereo(tx, rx, Ratio(format));

DateTime TotalDr = Convert.ToDateTime(TotalDuration);
```

i.e `TotalDuration` is first declared as long  and i want to change it to datetime

My question is: on line 2 only the first 2 is just a calculation in different method that works different tasks ...

Comment: What is returned in `TotalDuration` , is it Seconds, Milliseconds, Minutes, Ticks ???

Comment: sorry in line 3 ... it should return in hh:mm:ss format

Comment: You sure you want a `DateTime`? And not a `TimeSpan`? At least for the calculation?

Answer (score 2):

A duration is not the same thing as a time of day or a date, so you shouldn't even consider casting or converting it to a `DateTime`. Instead, look at the `TimeSpan` type, which you can use to correctly represent a duration of time.

What does your `CalcDurationForStereo()` method return? A number of seconds? Milliseconds? 100 nanosecond intervals? Depending on the scale of the return value, you can call different methods when creating a `TimeSpan` instance:

```
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TotalDuration); // or...
var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TotalDuration); // or...
var duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TotalDuration); // 100 nanosecond intervals

Debug.WriteLine("Time passed: " + duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
```

You can than use that duration to perform time arithmetic, adding to or subtracting from `DateTime` values such as `DateTime.Now`.

```
// Adding a TimeSpan to a DateTime
var inAWhile = DateTime.Now + duration;

// Subtracting a TimeSpan from a DateTime
var aWhileAgo = DateTime.Now - duration;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear exactly what you are trying to do, but perhaps you would be better off using an instance of [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead of `DateTime`.

**Create a TimeSpan:**

TimeSpan has a constructor that takes an Int64, representing number of ticks. Was this what you were looking fore perhaps? Otherwise there are similar constructors to provide the number of minutes, secconds, etc. instead.

**Print what you need from a TimeSPan:**

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(yourInt64Var);
string duration = t.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```

**Calculate the date from it:**

It should be easier to convert from `TimeSpan` to `DateTime` too, if you need that. As an example, this will give you a DateTime representing the date at a `yourInt64Variable` ticks from now:

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(yourInt64Variable);
DateTIme calculatedDate = DateTime.Now.Add(duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

You have to give a valid parameter to your `Conver.ToDateTime` (see link)

Answer (score 0):

If the long is supposed to represent the year, then you should use the **DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)** constructor passing arbitrary (according to your needs) values for month and day:

```
DateTime TotalDr = new DateTime(1, 1, TotalDuration);
```

If long is the number of thicks, then the **DateTime(Int64)** constructor is sufficient:

```
DateTime TotalDr = new DateTime(TotalDuration);
```

Comment: what is 1 ,1 and can DateTime TotalDr = new DateTime(TotalDuration); works  ??

Comment: 1, 1 are arbitrary values for the date of the month and the month itself. That is valid IF your long represents an year (for example, 1976).
If the long is a number of ticks ("A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar."), then the new DateTime(TotalDuration) will work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
DateTime TotalDr = new DateTime(TotalDuration);
```